# Fundamental group of subset in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider two coordinate planes
$$ P_1=\bigg\{(x, y, 0,0)\in \mathbb{ R}^4 \bigg\}\ {\rm and}\ P_2=\bigg\{(0,0, z, t) \in
\mathbb{R}^4\bigg\}$$ Note that the intersection is one point set,
i.e., origin.

Question : Then show that $$ \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^4-P_2) =0 $$ I can not convince
that this is true.

Proof : $P_1-P_2$ is a punctured plane. If $c$ is a closed curve
generating $\pi_1(P_1-P_2)$, then we want to find a two dimensional
disk $D$ in $  \mathbb{R}^4-P_2$ s.t. $\partial D=c$.

Here $c$ can be represented by $$\{ (Re^{it},0)\in\mathbb{C}^2|t\in
[0,2\pi] \}$$ for some large $R>0$. But I can not proceed any more.

Thank you in advance.

[Add]

By Moishe Cohen's comment, note that $\mathbb{R}^4-P_2 =\mathbb{R}^2\times (\mathbb{R}^2-\{ {\rm point} \})$. Hence fundamental group in Question is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint: The complement to each codimension 2 affine subspace in $R^n$ is homotopy-equivalent to the circle.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.